# jQuery animation i janky

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, i'm trying to create a smooth moving animation (left and right).

There is 2 galleries that shall move out of the page/into the page. It should move on the horizontal axis (funny enough). I have tried animating the margin-left in jQuery, but it's bad and janky. Here is a snippet of what i tried:

```
  $('.navArrowRight').click(function (){
    $('.galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'-105.5%'}, 1000);
    toggle();
});
$('.navArrowLeft').click(function (){
    $('.galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 1000);
    toggle();
});
```

I need it to move smooth, but i just haven't been able to crack the code on how to. I hope you guys on stack, can help!

So again: i need it to move on horizontal axis, the one galleri into the picture, and the other out of it. They both use the class `.galleri_container`, and it is div's that's moving.

Thanks

Comment: maybe it doesn't like that value -105.5% .  have you tried 106%? try creating a jsfiddle with css, js and html.  that will give people a better idea what's going on with your code.

Comment: You should try dropping a library like Velocity.js - http://julian.com/research/velocity/ jQuery animation is slow.

Comment: @Jake I'll check it out!

Comment: @Jake It looks good, i do wonder though, if this will work better in general with translate, and if so, how would i animal transform: translateX(-105.5%); in jQuery? The effect i try to achieve is a slide effect, between 2 containers. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating margin using JS, you could use CSS3 animations, which mostly are lot smoother and uses less CPU/GPU while running.

Try this CSS, and for animation just change element class (between **previous**, **active** and **next** accordingly) with jQuery.

```
.galleri_container.active {
    margin-left: 0%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;                  
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;                 
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;   
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;          
    transition: all 1s ease; }

.galleri_container.previous {
        margin-left: -105.5%; }

.galleri_container.next {
            margin-left: 105.5%; }
```

Comment: And that would be toggleClass()?